# I installed Chrome as root; why can't I run it either as root or normal user?

Tags: google-chrome

I installed Google Chrome while logged in as the root user but couldn't open it as root.

I then logged in via a normal user and tried to start Google Chrome but again, nothing happens.

I am not getting an error message or anything, Google Chrome just doesn't start.

Any ideas what is causing this issue and how I can fix it?

Comment: Can you try running Chrome from the terminal and posting errors you get?  Thanks.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to explain why you "installed Chrome via root"?

Comment: BTW, did you search for "how to install Chrome as root"? There are several hits with ways about doing so. But it's not something the "average" user should be doing, IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try in your terminal( <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +<kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>+T</kbd> ) with

```
gksudo google-chrome
```